# Wifi wont connect at start

Tags: networking

So I am sure it's a simple fix but I couldn't find anything on the forums or Google.

Pretty much when I boot up it wont connect to my wifi. I have to disable Wi-Fi then enable it for it to connect. So, Is there a way around this or a fix for it as repeating this constantly gets tedious. If you need any info, I'm fairly new to this so could you also explain how to get it!

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just click "connect"? Sometimes it helps to set a connection as "system connection", it can connect automatically then.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a .sh script to have this in it:

```
nmcli nm wifi off
nmcli nm wifi on
```

Then using this:

```
start on startup
task
exec /path/to/aboveScript.sh
```

Save this in a .conf file in ~/.config/upstart

To automatically start-up the script on start up!

Comment: If it didn't work just say, jeez, no need to take away the only rep I have for trying to help!

Comment: You will get you rep back if you delete this useless answer.

Comment: how's it useless!?!?  it works to disconnect & enable automatically on start up, which, is what BloodLines said he needed to do. With absolutely no additional information I couldn't suggest a fix, so I suggested a workaround!

Comment: Now after edit the commands to restart wifi are correct. But the rest of the answer is still bullshit. What is `start on startup`? Is it a terminal command or what? And all the rest lines...

Comment: it's a .conf file!

Comment: And I'm coming over from Mac and I'd learnt the original 1st piece of code turned off & started the wifi on Mac.

Comment: So, please do not suggest Mac commands for Ubuntu. they won't work. There is no `~/.config/upstart`, etc...

Comment: yes there is, 

'benny@BennyUbuntu:~/.config/upstart$'

 That, I have just copied and pasted from terminal, mate!

Comment: And I brought over the Mac terminal commands forgeting it was solely for Mac!

Comment: You can try to answer a more answerable question. This will be closed soon, I guess. And you did not lose any rep. You can't get less than 1.